# Jsoup not matching tags without certain attributes?

Tags: java, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jsoup

I have a function that, given a div element, will find all img elements within it.
The only problem is that only the first 3 are being selected. The only difference between the first 3 and the rest is the inclusion of attributes (class and alt)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dhgate.com/wholesale/kitchen-fixtures/c019034002-1.html").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("div.prolist");
for (Element e : elements) {
    String img[] = getImagesSrc(e, 1);
}
....
protected String[] getImagesSrc(Element e, int numOfImages) {
    String src[];
    src = new String[numOfImages];
    int i = 0;
    Elements imgElements = e.select("img[src]");
    for (Element o : imgElements) {
        System.out.println("html = " + o.outerHtml());
        src[i++] = o.attr("src");
    }
    return src;
}
```

**Some example div element** (These are what gets passed to the function)

```
<div class="prolist">
  <a href="some link"><img class="folder" alt="Folder" src="folder.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div...
...div>
<div class="prolist">
  <a href="some link"><img src="folder.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

Shouldn't I be getting all images regardless of the sttributes?

I have tested the code using the same HTML structure from the website and from localhost. The code DOES work on locahost but NOT on the website (www.dhgate.com)

**SOLVED - The site was using lazyload plugin so the HTML in the inspector was reading different from what Jsoup was. In my case I had to include 'a' tags that had [class~=lazyload]**

Comment: Please post a more complete example of the source HTML. Also, how are you calling `getImagesSrc()`? Please provide the calling metod, too.

Comment: Ideally this code should print all the img tags with a src attribute  as well as store the src in src array, but it depends on the element you pass as argument to the function. It might be that particular element which is missing the img tags.

Comment: I have doube and triple checked what is being passed to the function and it is exactly as the example element above

Comment: @MCL I am calling the function from my main body of code which scrapes other elements (and that all works). I should also say that the function didn't use to be a function, I rewrote it as a function to tidy up my own code. But the results I get are the same in either case.

Comment: You can edit your question and provide the additional information I asked about, no need to answer this in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The program does get the source of all img tags inside a div element with class prolist. But you should take into account some issue that may occur depending on you complete program.

```
for (Element e : elements) {
    String img[] = getImagesSrc(e, 1);
}
```

In the first loop the img array is overwritten on each iteration. So if you have multiple div elements with class prolist, the img tag array of each will overwrite the other. If you want to get the entire img or all div tags change the `getImagesSrc()` method argument to `Elements` and pass `doc.select("div.prolist")` directly.

The second argument for `getImagesSrc()` method is used to initialze the array. So in case if we have more than one img tags it will result in an ArrayOutOfBoundException. The number of image tags are indetermisnistic. So you should use a `List` in this case. If you want an array you can later make an array out of the list. For e.g

```
protected String[] getImagesSrc(Element e) {
    List<String> imgSources = new ArrayList<String>();
    Elements imgElements = e.select("img[src]");
    for (Element o : imgElements) {
       imgSources.add(o.attr("src"));
    }
    return imgSources.toArray(new String[imgSources.size()]);
}
```

Also note that since you are slecting img like  `e.select("img[src]");`, it'll only return img tags that has an src attribute.